# d3 regex or Notepad++ data cleaning

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

Messing around with various data viz technologies to figure out which one is best for a work-related task, I have found that I need to do some minor data cleaning.

I have a column "BookingID", in a csv, which has only two different possible entry formats:

```
"19028848
"
```

and

```
"27515492
AirBnB-16002513-4222RF"
```

Note that I am not sure why the quotation marks or new line breaks are there the way they are. Probably something to do with the fact that the original file was Excel and I used Excel to save as CSV.

In any case, I have the following d3 code which maps and filters the two columns of my CSV that I want as an array of arrays for d3 to use in scales mappings:

```
    sales = data
    .map(d => [+d["BookingID"], +d["Total Paid"]])
    .filter(results => results.every(not(isNaN)));
```

This works for all BookingIDs in the first format I wrote here, but not for the second (i.e. they get filtered out). I would like a solution to remove everything starting after the number, so that in the case of the example above, I end up with 27515492. I am not terribly experienced with all this, but I can't imagine people do much cleaning in d3, correct? Since I'm not sure if I'll be using d3, highcharts, Tableau, or something else in the end, for this I would like a solution at the excel spreadsheet or CSV in Notepad++ level. I just saw CSVed from another question, but I just need the best solution, not necessarily a GUI or anything fancy. I appreciate your recommendations (and regex expressions, you regex jedis) Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear but it seems a regex like `^(\d+) .*` to replace with `$1` in NPP should work.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure that works... https://regex101.com/r/gYVpwG/1

Comment: A regex for Npp does not have to work at regex101 as it does not support Boost regex flavor. Anyway I am on a mobile and cannot load regex101.

Comment: Did I get that right, the quotation marks and line breaks are part of your values? If they are, you need to put the first quotation mark in your regex `^"(\d+).*` https://regex101.com/r/gYVpwG/2.

Comment: Yes; thank you for that. Is $1 the correct thing to replace with? It seems to get rid of the first quotation mark but not the remaining AirBnB-16002513-4222RF" part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a regex, there is no need to pre-process your data in Notepad++, because all this could easily be done in JavaScript:

```js
// data contains the result of your CSV input processed by d3.csv()
var data = [{
  "BookingID": "19028848\n",
  "Total Paid": "1"
}, {
  "BookingID": "27515492\nAirBnB-16002513-4222RF",
  "Total Paid": "1"
}];

var sales = data
  .map(d => [
    +/^(\d+).*/.exec(d["BookingID"])[1],   // extract ID from input strings
    +d["Total Paid"]
  ]);

console.log(sales);
```

The regex `/^(\d+).*/` will extract the relevant part of the booking ID from both formats and feed the result right into your data processing.

Comment: I get TypeError: /^"(\d+).*/.exec(...) is null in the console. I don't understand this given the regex search input is never null (I checked...)?

Comment: @FredericBastiat This will happen if there is no match found for the regex (have a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Return_value)), when `.exec()` returns `null`. This should not be the case if really *all* your `BookingID`s did adhere to the two formats you listed. If there are any other formats or null values, you have to account for that, too.

Comment: I appreciate the insight. I'll inspect my data some more and see what's going on.

Comment: Still no luck, and my data is only in those two formats. Notepad++ will even find and replace using the regex provided, but I would like a solution with javascript as well. The line +/^"(\d+).*/.exec(d["BookingID"])[1] has +/^ highlighted as normal code and starting with the quotation mark, everything in the rest of the line is greyed out except for "BookingID". I need to escape the regex out in some way. I am having trouble as I already tried adding a / after the ^ and got a SyntaxError missing ] after element list...

Comment: To escape a character within the regex you need to put a **backslash** in front of the character. In your comment you mentioned using a slash which would end the regex at that point resulting in an error as you experienced. On the other hand the snippet in my answer works for me in both cases showing the validity of the regex for your two formats. To get further help it might be helpful to set up an executable demo to fiddle around with.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I am able to isolate the regex code with parentheses and it still gives me a null input typeerror. What are some other reasons this regex input may be null? Do I need to reset the internal cursor? How would I do that if so?

Comment: Have a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2smekk29/) which features one entry having a different format. This entry will get logged to the console as an error. I modified the code to log all entries which result in `null` when being searched for the id and to return only those having all numerical ids. You can use this code to sift through your data to identify any deviations from the formats mentioned.

Comment: The regex will match a quotation mark at the beginning of the line immediately followed by one or more consecutive numerical digits. Possible sources of error are: a) the quotation mark is missing or it is not at the very start of the line, b) there are one or more spaces or any other characters between the quotation mark and the first digit. In any of these cases the regex will return `null`. On the other hand anything following the group of digits will have no effect on the result and will not cause any error.

Comment: Hmm do you think it could be that there is a header row that starts with BookingID in my csv so it looks for the regex there first? That seems likely to me since it isn't case a or b anywhere else as you mentioned. How can I get around this? My code above is in the callback for my function loading csv using d3 as such: d3.csv("####.csv", function(data) { }

Comment: `d3.csv()` will yield an array of objects, which contains no header line. Have you tried to integrate the error logging from my JSFiddle? Did it log any errors? For anything beyond this you should take my advice from above and set up a JSFiddle or some other runnable demo yourself, which exhibits the issue.

Comment: Wait a minute: I think, this might be a red herring! My [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333045/d3-regex-or-notepad-data-cleaning/42333887?noredirect=1#comment71819797_42333045) on your question about the quotation mark was only valid for executing the regex search in NPP as you originally asked for. However, D3 will take care of the quotation marks while processing the strings, i.e. there will be no extra quotation marks in your `data`. Your regex should be just `/^(\d+).*/` without the quotation mark.

Comment: Thank you for that, that's exactly right. One more thing, what would you use as the find and replace in Notepad++ to do the same thing with find-and-replace?